# activity to dispatch or redirect to other activities

Tags: java, android

I want to create a dispatcher activity, defined with `android.intent.action.MAIN`, which will do nothing but call some custom methods and eventually `startActivity(Intent)`, based upon certain criteria. This activity has nothing to display/render to the user.

What best practices should I follow? Of course, I wish to incur the least rendering time (nothing to display), but I will need to use the `Context` for other actions in determining which `Activity` to redirect to.

So far I can think of:

1. `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"`
2. `android:stateNotNeeded="true"`
3. Call `finish()` after calling `startActivity(Intent)` in dispatcher activity

Answer (score 0):

You should consider putting the finish() function in the onPause(...) method. When the other Activity comes in foreground, the onPause(...) of the dispatcher Activity will be called by the system normally and if you call the finish() here, you can be sure that the dispatcher Activity will be finished when another comes in foreground.